# android listview with Buttons how to get the value

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick, android-arrayadapter

i have a listView with a TextView and 3 Buttons in each row.
Now what I need is -whenever a Button is clicked the value of the textView in that specific row.

### ListView

### [Text][Button 1][Button 2][Button 3]

### [Text][Button 1][Button 2][Button 3]

### [Text][Button 1][Button 2][Button 3]

any suggestions?

my code:

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<User> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();

        holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);

        holder.btn1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.btn2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        holder.btn3 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    User user = data.get(position);
    holder.textName.setText(user.getName());

    holder.textName.setTag(position);

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "B 1 button Clicked" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    holder.btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "B 2 button Clicked" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    holder.btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "B 3 button Clicked" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return row;

}

static class UserHolder {
    TextView textName;

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
}
```

}

Comment: within your `onclick` write `String name=holder.textName.getText().toString();`

Comment: Did U need value of text view or U need to know that which button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

use `holder.textName.getText().toString();` to getText from the Textview

```
holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "B 1 button Clicked" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         String Textname= holder.textName.getText().toString();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`String s = holder.textName.getText().toString();`

print `s` and show the value of the TextView.